# How to access a Lisp symbol function cell

Tags: lisp, symbols

If I create this function

```
(defun a (&rest x)
    x)
```

I have a new function that imitates the `list` function. As I have read, I have done something to the "function cell" of the symbol `a`. Before I created and evaluated the function above, I would have gotten a

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: a
```

If I would have tried something like `(a 'b)`. Good. Now, is there a way to see exactly what these symbol cells contain, how they hold onto a plist, a value, and in my case, a function, e.g., their data structures and how they're joined to the symbol? I've heard that you can actually go into these symbol cells and manipulate them. I'm using elisp, but any Lisp lore on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at `symbol-function`, `symbol-plist`, `symbol-value`, `symbol-macro-expand` and `symbol-macrolet`.

In your example:

```
(symbol-function 'a) =>
#<FUNCTION A (&REST X) (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN A)) (BLOCK A X)>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp one can use the function `describe` to get infos about a symbol:

```
* (defun a (&rest x)
    x)
A
* (describe 'a)
COMMON-LISP-USER::A
  [symbol]

A names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (&REST X)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION * (VALUES LIST &OPTIONAL))
  Source form:
    (LAMBDA (&REST X) (BLOCK A X))
```